# The tangent bundle of $\mathbb{CP}^1$ is not isomorphic to its dual.

Tags: algebraic-topology, smooth-manifolds, characteristic-classes

This question is related to [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/565235/the-complex-tangent-bundle-of-mathbbcp1-is-not-isomorphic-to-its-conjugate) but is not a duplicate. In " Characteristic Classes" by Milnor and Stasheff on pages 167-168, the authors give a brief argument about why the tangent bundle of the complex projective line $\tau_1$ is not isomorphic to its dual.

The argument says that if it were isomorphic, the isomorphism would map a tangent space to itself (and reverse orientation); one could then deduce the existence of a nowhere zero tangent line field on the sphere which is a contradiction. However, an isomorphism of vector bundles doesn't need to map a fiber to itself. It just should be a homeomorphism of the total space and map fibers isomorphically to fibers (page 14), or am I wrong?

Anyway, why isn't $\tau_1$ isomorphic to its dual?

Comment: One way to say it is that the first Chern class of the tangent bundle is not equal to its negative, or equivalently because it is not $2$-torsion.

Comment: (1) Am I right that an isomorphism doesn't need to cover the identity? (2) If yes, why couldn't the pullback of an isomorphism (of $\tau_1$ and $\overline{\tau_1}$) take $c_1(\tau_1)=-c_1(\overline{\tau_1})$ to $-c_1(\tau_1)$? Thanks for the comments.

Comment: 1) An isomorphism should cover the identity. 2) Characteristic classes are isomorphism invariants.

Comment: 1) In the definition of an isomorphism, Milnor doesn't say it byt that may be a mistake. So bundles with different but homeomorphic base spaces cannot be isomorphic? 2) Yes, but an isomorphism *would* take $c_1(something)$ to $c_1(something \,else)$ which happens to be $-c_1(something)$. I see no contradiction..

Comment: 1) It's a mistake. 2) I don't understand your question. The first Chern class of a line bundle is a particular element of a particular group, namely $H^2(X, \mathbb{Z})$. It's known that if a line bundle has first Chern class $c_1$, then its dual has first Chern class $- c_1$, and that two line bundles are isomorphic iff their first Chern classes are equal. If $c_1 \neq - c_1$, then it follows that the corresponding line bundle is not isomorphic to its dual.

Comment: 1) So it doesn't make sense to speak about isomorphic bundles with different base spaces? 2) I though that it might happen that $c_1(\tau_1)$ and $c_1(\overline{\tau_1})$ might be different elements of $H^2$ but one would be pullback of the other under the homeomorphism of the base space. But if it is the identity as you say, then this cannot happen. So my problem is probably in the definition of isomorphism..

Comment: 1) It makes sense to speak about a bundle being isomorphic to the pullback of some other bundle via some fixed map, but you should fix the map when you do this. 2) As I said, an isomorphism of vector bundles should cover the identity.

Comment: Ok, if an isomorphism needs to cover the identity, then all is clear. I found this definition a bit strange, but ok. Thanks you.

Comment: The problem with not fixing the map is that you'd end up identifying two vector bundles which are related by an automorphism of your base space, which is an extra layer of difficulty and just not what people mean by an isomorphism of vector bundles by default. I mean, when I talk about a function on a space, I don't automatically identify two functions when they're related by an automorphism of the space.

Comment: Now I understand, thanks. But it is at least not clear whether $\tau_1$ is "isomorphic" to its dual in this broader sense, right?

Comment: I would strongly prefer that you not use "isomorphic" for this equivalence relation. Say "related by an automorphism of $\mathbb{CP}^1$" or something. You can take an automorphism that reverses orientations.